# Como deslogar corretamente o usuário após um tempo de inatividade?

Tags: php

**RESPOSTA**

Segue abaixo a resposta para quem tiver passando por algo parecido. Primeiro criei um campo a mais na minha tabela chamada **TempoAtivo** onde armazeno o time() assim que o usuário se loga. Veja abaixo:

```
$tempoAtivo = time() + 30;
```

Após armazenado, criei um novo arquivo chamado online que funciona da seguinte forma:

```
 <script>
setInterval(function(){
    $("#verOnline").load(location.href+" #verOnline");
    }, 2000);
</script>
<div id="verOnline">
<?php
$tempoAtual = time();
    $tempoAtivo = time() + 30;
       $alterar = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE proj_acessos SET Tempo = '".$tempoAtivo."' WHERE IdUsuarios = ".$_SESSION['IdUsuarios']."");
     $alterar = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE proj_acessos SET StatusOnline = 'N' WHERE Tempo < ".$tempoAtual."");
?>
</div>
```

O código acima atualiza de 2 em 2 minutos a base  de dados com o tempo ativo do usuário. Caso o usuário saia do sistema diretamente pelo browser, o tempo para de atualizar no banco e quando o tempo atual for maior que o tempo no banco de dados, o status muda para offline.

Comment: A pergunta foi editada e neste momento está completamente diferente da original, e as respostas agora parece que nada têm a ver com a pergunta. se a pergunta mudou, cria-se outra. se não mudou, adiciona-se mais informação à original. assim não me parece bem.

Comment: José, por favor, evita editar sua pergunta de forma tão drástica, caso contrário as respostas existentes são invalidadas. Também não adicione uma resposta na própria pergunta. Achar a solução por conta própria é excelente, parabéns! Mas aí você pode responder à sua próxima pergunta usando o formulário abaixo desta página. Eu reverti sua edição e juntei a pergunta original com a resposta. Sugiro que coloque a segunda parte como uma nova resposta, depois edite a pergunta e remova esse trecho de lá. Você também pode marcar sua própria resposta como certa, se achar que deve fazer isto. Abraço!

Comment: a lógica é simples e a implementação pode se dar de várias formas. Uma forma é usando node.js. Exemplos diversos encontra-se na web.. https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/node-js-websocket-near-real-offlineonline-check/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você terá que fazer algo como isto:

```
if (empty($_SESSION)) session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['lastAccess'])) $_SESSION['lastAccess'] = time();
else {
    $_SESSION['lastAccess'] -= time();
}

if ($_SESSION['lastAccess'] > time()+5) {
    session_destroy();
    echo('session timeout');
}
```

Explicando:
Se não houver session, começar uma;
Se não houver "last access" então o ultimo acesso é igual a agora;
Ou então, retira o agora ao tempo do ultimo acesso
se o ultimo acesso for maior do que agora mais 5segunfos, então a sessão expirou

**Isto é um bocado pseudo-code que eu já não tenho um ambiente de PHP para testar o código**

Quanto à segunda duvida, alguem no SO inglês fez [uma maravilhosa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854246/587811)

Comment: Certo Mosh, mas nesse caso não iremos esbarrar no que o BlunT falou sobre atualização da página, já que roda no servidor?

Comment: Sendo que nós gravamos o `lastAccess` na `session` do utilizador E estamos a bater o `lastAccess` contra o tempo em que a página está a ser loaded; Não, não esbarra no que o @BlunT disse :)

Comment: Perfeito Mosh. Vou fazer um teste aqui com seu código....

Comment: @Jose.Marcos depois diz se funcionou e se trocou alguma coisa, p'ra ver se eu preciso de mudar alguma coisa na resposta :)

Comment: @MosMage, mil perdões. Ainda estou me acostumando com o site. O seu código funcionou corretamente e coloquei como resposta. Obrigado. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

o código php só é executado uma vez, quando a página é carregada.

Isto não faz nada:

```
if($segundos > $limite){
    session_destroy();
    echo "<script>alert('Sua sessão acabou!'); window.location.href='../index.php';</script>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['Time'] = time();
}
```

a não ser que a variavel $segundos seja maior que o $limite quando o script for executado, ou se a página estiver constantemente a ser refrescada (coisa que não se deve fazer).

Essa validação deveria estar do lado do cliente, em javascript.

Comment: Desculpem a demora na resposta... certo BlunT, vc teria algum exemplo pra me mostrar, pois procurei algo na internet e nao achei... acredito que nao tenha procurado da forma correta...

Comment: Existe o session_cache_expire(). Pelo que entendi, ele se renova a cada vez que o usuário acessar a session_start(), correto? Agora se o usuário estiver no chat por exemplo de uma determinada página e o tempo estiver para 15 min, corre o risco da session_cache_expire(15) deslogar o usuário?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos exemplo do quê mais especificamente? O que é que não está a conseguir fazer?

Comment: Olá BlunT.. o MoshMage me passou um código em PHP por inatividade, porém acredito que tem que ser do lado do cliente em javascript. Preciso que se o usuário ficar muito tempo inativo, ele seja desligado do sistema e redirecionado para a página de login. Isso seria um saída para o que estou procurando em relação do usuário fechar o browser sem sair pelo sistema. Quando ele faz isso, o status do usuário fica online sem estar...

Comment: @Jose.Marcos uma das formas de fazer isso é ter um código javascript que de X em X segundos vai buscar uma página ex. ping.php. Essa página deve devolver um resultado diferente caso a sessão já tenha expirado, e nesse caso o javascript redirecciona o utilizador para a página de login

Comment: Certo BlunT... perdoe-me a ignorância, pois sou leigo em javascript, vc teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Consegui esse código, porém ele direciona mesmo clicando ou mexendo com o mouse: var timeout;
function set(){
 timeout = setTimeout(function(){
 window.location.href = window.location.href = "index.php";
 }, 120000);
}

function clear(){
 clearTimeout(timeout);
}

window.onload = function(){
 document.onmousemove = function(){
 clear();
 set();
 }
 document.onclick = function(){
 clear();
 set();
 }
}

Comment: @Jose.Marcos não tenho aqui nenhum exemplo que lhe possa fornecer. o mais simples será usar jQuery e um request ajax, mas sem conhecimentos não vai ser fácil. a minha sugestão é ir ao site do jquery e procurar exemplos de $.ajax